# Tradingview - I need to get highest and lowest price on the message box of alert

Tags: pine-script

[image]

what I need is to get Highest and Lowest price, when the closed price broken the channel.
I can get many different prices by writing {{close}}, {{open}}, {{high}}, {{low}} in the message box, But the highest and lowest price How can I get it

Answer (score 0):

Since you already plot them, you can use the `{{plot_n}}` placeholders in your alert message.

> {{plot_0}}, {{plot_1}}, … {{plot_19}} — corresponding series of an
> indicator that is used to set an alert. The indicator series are
> values that you see on a chart.

Please see #5 in [this](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/introducing-variables-in-alerts-14880/) link.

Comment: you are great sir, yes it is work well... If I need to add plotshape below them for example {{plot_0}}; {{plot_1}}; {{plotshape_2}} it is not working I mean {{plotshape_2}}. what shall I write? Please give me answer and than you

Comment: What value do you want to get from `plotshape()` ?

Comment: I need to get support and resistance levels, Kindly send the attached codes:

Comment: Hello expert, I need to get support and Resistance levels, please see the attached codes for plotshape -->> plotshape(ph and showpp, text='H', style=shape.labeldown, color=na, textcolor=color.new(color.red, 0), location=location.abovebar, offset=-prd)
-->> plotshape(pl and showpp, text='L', style=shape.labelup, color=na, textcolor=color.new(color.lime, 0), location=location.belowbar, offset=-prd)

Comment: Sir, can you please to check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72502813/trading-view-i-need-to-get-support-and-resistance-prices-wen-i-have-an-alert-t